# Struct, is fundamental template,C++

Tags: c++, templates, std, primitive-types, enable-if

I want to check whether the template parameter of the struct is fundamental or not.
So I created a struct

```
template<typename T, typename =  std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental_v<T>>>
struct Something {
};
```

And an empty struct

```
struct AStruct{
};
```

Using `is_fundamental` I expected that my struct will be "enabled" only and only if the template parameter `T` is one of the fundamental types like `long long int` , `float` and others...

But when I do specialization like

```
using Defined = Something<AStruct>;
```

It compiles fine, so what have I missed? or what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `std::enable_if_t<std::is_fundamental_v<T>>` (_t added) or `typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental_v<T>>::type`.

I would suggest `static_assert` instead:

- avoid the hijack with `Something<AStruct, void>` (can also be fixed with preferred `std::enable_if_t<cond, int> = 0`)
- Your class would not be SFINAE friendly anyway, so that hard error allow custom message.
- Simpler syntax :)

Comment: Your answer worked for me, anyway I am now thinking about using `static_assert `.